# Does gSuite (as distinct from GCP) support "service accounts"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-workspace

- We are using gSuite (GMail, Drive, etc.).
- We haven't taken any action with regards to GCP.
- We want to create a service account that can be used to manipulate things in Drive that it is given access to.

Can that be done?

As far as I can tell, every path for creating a service account starts with the assumption that we are users of GCP. However, as best I can tell, nobody in the org has set up, configured, etc. GCP usage and I'd rather not change that. So, unless gSuite usage automatically involves GCP usage (or we did set it up and then forgot about it), I need some way to create a service account other than thought GCP.

Either that or I need to chose some solution other than Drive.

Answer (score 1):

### If you have a GSuite account, you automatically have access to the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)

- Accessing the Cloud console is important for all kind of development related settings, as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-console).
- Among others - creating and managing credentials for client access, enabling APIs, creating Addons, managing quotas and - creating creedntials for a service account.
- So yes, you need to use the Cloud Console to set up up a service account, abut as a GSuite user you can access the platform with your usual credentials and the steps are well [explained](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys).

Comment: Okay... do you have a citation on that first assertion? My concern stems from that the console link from above is leading to what seems to be a "new costumer" UI flow; it's asking me, personally, to accept a ToS that I would expect to have already been done once for the whole org.

Comment: Are you the admin of your GSuite account?

Comment: Even if you are not, the GCP console will be enabled as soon as you accept the Therms and Conditions. Without accessing the GCP you won't be able to create Service Account credentials that you need to insert into your code in order to use the service account.

Comment: It's seeming that the main issue here is that the UX is confusing things by making the "new user of an existing gSuit account" flow look like it's a "new gSuite/GCP account" flow. -- At this point it's moot because I switched the plan to S3, which I already had available credentials for.

Comment: Chose the solution the suits you best, just remember that for a GSuite service account you need 1. Create it in GCP, 2. Give it the necessary scopes and delegation in your admin console.

Comment: Also one thing to note is that onboarding onto GCP and using Cloud Console is not equivalent to allowing the use of billable GCP resources, you need to create a billing account for that. I.e. if you skip adding a payment method, you won't be able to incur any costs but you'll still be able to use IAM, Service Accounts, create projects, configure OAuth2 clients, etc.